# Необходимо при клике менять текст, а при повторном менять на начальный

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

HTML:

```
<p id="p" align="center" width="100%" style=" border:1px solid red; background:#ffffcc; font-weight:900; padding:5px ">
    Спрятать фото
</p>
```

JQuery:

```
$("#p").on("click", function () {
    $(".head-moto-img").slideToggle(2000, function () {
        $("#p").text("Показать фото")
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Хорошей практикой является полное разделение стилей, скриптов и контента. Также рекомендую для кликабельных элементов использовать `<button>`, так как он имеет возможность получать фокус с клавиатуры, и его можно стилизировать как угодно.

```js
$('button.toggle').on('click', function () {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
button.toggle {
  border: 1px solid red; 
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: yellow;
  color: green;
}
button.toggle.active {
  color: red;
}

button.toggle .show { display: inline; }
button.toggle .hide { display: none; }

button.toggle.active .show { display: none; }
button.toggle.active .hide { display: inline; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="toggle">
  <span class="show">Показать фото</span>
  <span class="hide">Спрятать фото</span>
</button>
```

Comment: Я не понимаю, зачем выносить что-то в css, если то же самое делает методы `toggle() / show() / hide()`?

Comment: Затем, что может менятся еще и стиль. Кнопка может становиться красной или зеленой в разной ситуации. Еще может быть пассивной... Поэтому универсально - все это разделить.

Comment: если задача стоит в переключении видимости, то вынос в css кажется каким-то оверхедом "на всякий случай". Преждевременная оптимизация / расширение функционала / рефакторинг - тоже плохо

Comment: Не думаю, что show() / hide() в данном случае прямо таки супер-оптимизация... все равно кнопку надо будет КАК-ТО стилизировать... На вкус и на цвет...

Comment: И еще в моем варианте можно задать начальное состояние кнопки просто добавив к ней класс `active`, и при этом она не потребует начального запуска JS.

Answer (score 0):

Мой вариант решения данной задачи. Используется только JS, без добавления ненужных классов и стилей. Здесь используется стандартный обмен значениями по кругу и метод `text()`. Варианты текста устанавливаются в переменных `textDefault` - тест по умолчанию, и `textOther` - альтернативный текст.

```js
var textDefault = 'Тестовый текст';
var textOther = 'Другой текст';

$('#test-button').text(textDefault);

$('#test-button').click(function() {
  textDefault = textOther;
  textOther = $('#test-button').text();
  $('#test-button').text(textDefault);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="test-button"></button>
```

Comment: И вы получаете полностью немаcштабируемое решение. Что если понадобятся разные кнопки `[Показать/скыть фото]`, `[Показать/скрыть текст]`, `[Включить/выключить видео]`. 100 раз дублировать ваш скрипт?